# Vue mousemove only after mousedown

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, mousedown

How can I trigger a mousemove only if the element is clicked first?
I'm trying to utilize this for an audio player timeline.

```
.player__time--bar(@mousedown="setNewCurrentPosition($event)")
    .slider(role="slider" aria-valuemin="0" :aria-valuenow="currentPosition" :aria-valuemax="trackTotalDuration" aria-orientation="horizontal")
        .player__time--bar-current-position(:style="{width:  (100 / (trackTotalDuration / currentPosition)) + '%'}")
```

The method:

```
setNewCurrentPosition(e) {
    let tag = e.target
    // if the click is not on 'slider', grab div with class 'slider'
    if (e.target.className === 'player__time--bar') tag = e.target.firstElementChild
    else if (e.target.className === 'player__time--bar-current-position') tag = e.target.parentElement
    const pos = tag.getBoundingClientRect()
    const seekPos = (e.clientX - pos.left) / pos.width
    this.currentPosition = parseInt(this.trackTotalDuration * seekPos)
    // updates the time in the html
    this.$refs.player.currentTime = this.currentPosition
},
```

Comment: What error are you getting?  Is something in the code you provided not working?

Comment: Set a variable on mousedown on the time-bar. Unset the variable on mouseup anywhere. Wrap your mousemove in an `if` that checks whether the variable is set.

Comment: @RoyJ ok that it’s very doable but how do I call the function mousemove

Comment: @PatrickSteele what I have is working only on click. I want to be able to move the position ben if you click and drag. Basically sort of emulate the input type range

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You will want to have a `mousedown` listener on your element that sets a variable to indicate dragging started. Put a listener on the window to catch `mouseup` anywhere and unset the variable.

You can put `mousemove` on the element if you are only interested in dragging that happens inside the element. Otherwise you can put the `mousemove` listener on `window` so you catch it everywhere.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    dragging: false,
    x: 'no',
    y: 'no'
  },
  methods: {
    startDrag() {
      this.dragging = true;
      this.x = this.y = 0;
    },
    stopDrag() {
      this.dragging = false;
      this.x = this.y = 'no';
    },
    doDrag(event) {
      if (this.dragging) {
        this.x = event.clientX;
        this.y = event.clientY;
      }
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    window.addEventListener('mouseup', this.stopDrag);
  }
});
```

```css
.dragstartzone {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div class="dragstartzone" @mousedown="startDrag" @mousemove="doDrag">Start dragging here</div>
  <div>X: {{x}}, Y: {{y}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great! Thank you. I readjusted it a bit to fit my need. I will post code snippet below

Comment: There's still an issue... not really working on mobile :/

Comment: Right. You'll have to work with [touch events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events) since there's no mouse button. Should be the same things with touchstart touchend and touchmove.

Comment: Not having much luck with it, I don't think Vue supports @touch... by default

Comment: Nevermind, all figured out. Just had to grab some different properties. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the code provided by Roy J, refactoring it a bit to fit my need. Here it is

Template:

```
.player__time--bar(@mousedown="startDrag($event)" @mouseup="stopDrag($event)" @mousemove="doDrag($event)")
    .slider(role="slider" aria-valuemin="0" :aria-valuenow="currentPosition" :aria-valuemax="trackTotalDuration" aria-orientation="horizontal")
        .player__time--bar-current-position(:style="{width:  (100 / (trackTotalDuration / currentPosition)) + '%'}")
```

Data:

```
data: () => ({
    currentPosition: 0,
    trackTotalDuration: 0,
    dragging: false
}),
```

Methods:

```
startDrag() {
    this.dragging = true
},
stopDrag(event) {
    this.dragging = false
    this.setNewCurrentPosition(event)
},
doDrag(event) {
    if (this.dragging) this.setNewCurrentPosition(event)
},

setNewCurrentPosition(e) {
    let tag = e.target
    // if the click is not on 'slider', grab div with class 'slider'
    if (e.target.className === 'player__time--bar') tag = e.target.firstElementChild
    else if (e.target.className === 'player__time--bar-current-position') tag = e.target.parentElement
    const pos = tag.getBoundingClientRect()
    const seekPos = (e.clientX - pos.left) / pos.width
    this.currentPosition = parseInt(this.trackTotalDuration * seekPos)
    // updates the time in the html
    this.$refs.player.currentTime = this.currentPosition
},
```